# How to verify if a file is a valid excel spreadsheet?

Tags: c#, file, excel, interop

I already did some search here on SO, on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236926/how-do-i-programatically-interface-an-excel-spreadsheet), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613898/how-to-read-an-excel-spreadsheet-in-c-sharp-quickly), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409351/how-to-read-data-from-excel-spreadsheet) and more, but no clue, so I'm going to have to ask you guys.

I'm trying to open an Excel file via Interop, and I have Office 2007 installed, so I'm using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` version `14.0`.

When I try to open a valid `xls` file, everything runs fine.

But if I try to open an invalid file (like a bitmap, or an executable) via Interop, Excel opens it without complain or warning.

How can I detect Excel has an invalid workbook file loaded, without blocking with an alert ?

I'm trying to write a unit test of my Excel object reader. One of the cases is to try to open an invalid file.

Some code to help: 
Application Creation:

```
    _app = new Application()
        {
            Visible = false,
            DisplayAlerts = false,     // <-- I don't want to remove this.
            AskToUpdateLinks = false,
        };
```

Workbook opening:

```
   _workbooks.Open(filename);
   _workbook = _workbooks.get_Item(1); // 1-based.
   _worksheets = _workbook.Sheets;
```

EDIT:
Just to add 1 more information: Excel loads the invalid file. If `DisplayAlerts` is set to true, it complains (open a dialog) informing the workbook seems to be corrupted, but if `DisplayAlerts` is set to false, it loads the file just as below:

[image: Excel Loads Invalid File]

Comment: well one way around check for valid file ext .csv or xls seems to be the simplest approach...

Comment: You might see if the _app.Ready property goes to false when loading an invalid file. Just a thought I haven't tried it.

Comment: @DJ KRAZE, I already check the extension before loading the file. But what if someone changes the file extension and try to load an .exe instead ?

Comment: @Tod, just checked: _app.Ready remains `true` before and after loading the invalid file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just ended using another approach: Excel workbooks have a property called `FileFormat`. When Excel opens an invalid file, it sets the file format to one of the enumerator values of text:

```
    XlFileFormat.xlTextMac
    XlFileFormat.xlTextMSDOS
    XlFileFormat.xlTextPrinter
    XlFileFormat.xlTextWindows
```

And inside this enumeration Excel has the *valid* files (valid for my purpose):

```
    XlFileFormat.xlExcel12
    XlFileFormat.xlExcel7
    XlFileFormat.xlExcel8
    XlFileFormat.xlExcel9795
```

So I ended using a simple "`or`" to filter the kind of file I'd like to import:

```
    bool validFile = ( f == XlFileFormat.xlExcel12   ) 
                  || ( f == XlFileFormat.xlExcel7    ) 
                  || ( f == XlFileFormat.xlExcel8    ) 
                  || ( f == XlFileFormat.xlExcel9795 );
```

And now it works. Thanks for your help guys, you set me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the workbook count before and after loading the file. If both counts are the same, the file failed to load.

```
int countBefore = _workbooks.get_Count();
_workbooks.Open(filename);
int countAfter = _workbooks.get_Count();
if (countBefore == countAfter) {
    // The file failed to load.
}
```

Comment: Nice! But count sums 1, because TCHAN RAM! Excel loads the invalid file. But it does not look like a spreadsheet, because Excel loads the content of the file oddly. Look the edit, please.